# Dynamic Access Form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am creating a dynamic form in Access 2003. Each time the form is opened combo boxes are created based on table of "keywords." My code is having trouble deleting old boxes (or their labels, I'm not sure) and every opening after the first gets hung up on duplicate names (Run-time error '2450').

Secondly, junction table holding the "checked" keywords will fills up at a low finite amount.

Thirdly, I can't figure out how to populate the combo boxes based on the junction table records. When the form is loaded the boxes are always unchecked.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please epxlain your objective.  Frequently folks creating controls as required can be given an alternative.  Also if you distribute your app as an MDE/ACCDE this won't be possible.

Comment: Let me second Tony's point -- creating controls at runtime is not going to work in the long run, as eventually you hit the 700-odd upper limit of controls, and you have to start over with a new form. For what it's worth, the replication conflict resolution wizard that shipped with Access 97 (before they started using the global one for both Jet and SQL Server) was written by Michael Kaplan. He said he added 510 invisible controls to the form and then revealed the ones that were needed, precisely because of the 700-odd control limit (I forget the exact number -- it's not an intuitive one).

Comment: Objective 1: Allow user to assign "keywords" to records.
Objective 2: Allow form to be easily modified as "keywords" are updated. ("Keywords" will change so it is less than ideal to hardcode them to the form).

Thanks for the heads-up on the MDE. This is an in-house app, but will be good to know in the future.

Also, there will less than 200 keywords/controls.

I fixed the first issue of deleting old controls/labels. 

However, the limit of the number of records in the junction table appears to be the number of records in the "keywords" table. Any thoughts?

Comment: "Secondly, junction table holding the "checked" keywords will fills up at a low finite amount."   What do you mean by this?

Comment: I don't think you've described the problem well. You've said why the solution you came up with doesn't work, but I don't have a clear idea of what task you're attempting. In short, you've told us what solution doesn't work, but have not at any point described the situation and objectives. It sounds to me like you have a design error somewhere in your conception, as I"ve never needed 200 controls on a form, ever.

Comment: There are thousands of records that will eventually be gone through one by and each assigned keywords. These keywords are mostly static, but may have slight modifications every 3-4 months. As the user adds/deletes/changes a keyword in the keywords table, I would like this to be reflected on the form. The alternative I am trying to avoid is having bound controls on the form that would need to be updated every time the keywords table is updated. If there is a “right” way to do this please let me know. To date, my problem is getting the junction table to have more records than the keywords table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using a continuous subform bound to a junction table with one record per keyword and main record.  The kwyword would be a combo box.   Ensure you have a "dupe check" index based on both the foriegn main record key and the foriegn keyword key on the junction table.

Comment: I believe I have my junction table set up as you describe, it stores one keyword ID and one main record ID per junction record. However, the junction table will not store more records than the Keyword table. Why is this and how do I fix it? Also, what makes a subform continuous? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Change the forms Default View to Continuous Forms.   Move the labels to the header and move the controls so they run horizontally.  Or create a new form using the wizard but make it tabulur.

Comment: What message are you getting when you are unable to add records. I suspect you have a foreign key specified as being no duplicates allowed in the index.

Comment: The junction table is updating fine now, it was a small glich with my SQL statement. Thanks for the help on the "continuous forms," I forgot their name. As a side note, when I add a control with CreateControl() it is added on the uppermost layer and not associated with anything else on the form. Is it possble to add the control to a tab without using a subform?

Answer (score 0):

Do you explicitly destroy the created controls when you close the form? I'm not sure how Access handles stuff like this, but in Delphi when you create a control and put it on a form (all in code) the control is not destroyed when the form is destroyed. For that to work, you must set the owner property of the new control to the form. Maybe Access has a similar possibility?

Comment: The controls are updated when the form is loaded. First the old ones are deleted, then all the new ones are created based on a "keywords" table. To get the controls to update the junction table they cannot be bound to the form (because this form is bound to another table)

Comment: Access forms ARE NOT Delphi forms, so the way Delphi works has nothing to do with it. Controls added at runtime increment the counter for maximum number of controls addable to the form during the form's total lifetime, not just the current instance. THIS IS THE WAY ACCESS WORKS, and it's way dynamically adding controls is a bad idea. In addition, as Tony says, it won't work in an MDE, because design changes are not allowed in an MDE at all.